# iOS Safari shows apps that are installed. How does this work? Meta tag?

Tags: ios, ios6, mobile-safari

Have you noticed that some sites in iOS safari will show a banner to let the user know the app is installed? How does this work? Is this a meta tag?

[image: Airbnb example showing a banner to open the app]

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should include `<meta name="apple-itunes-app" content="app-id=myAppStoreID, affiliate-data=myAffiliateData, app-argument=myURL">` in your webpage's **head**.

Please check this link for more information: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/PromotingAppswithAppBanners/PromotingAppswithAppBanners.html

**NOTE**: It only works with iOS6 or later!